# `sudo -u user` in shebang line

Tags: sudo, shebang

I'd like to be able to run a script as another user, and only as that user.

The way I currently have this set up is to have

```
alice   ALL = (bob) NOPASSWD: /home/alice/script.sh
```

in the sudoers file and

```
alice@foo:~$ ls script.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  root ..... script.sh

alice@foo:~$ lsattr script.sh
----i----------- script.sh

alice@foo:~$ head -1 script.sh
#!/bin/bash

alice@foo:~$ sudo -u bob ./script.sh
ok
```

---

Is there a way to have the shebang line be something like

```
#!/usr/bin/sudo -u bob -- /bin/bash
```

so that alice could just run

```
alice@foo:~$ ./script.sh
ok
```

?

If I try this I simply get the error message

```
sudo: unknown user:  blog -- /bin/bash
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: as far as I know, sudo doesn't work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux (like many other Unix variants) only supports passing a single argument to the interpreter of a script. (The interpreter is the program on the shebang line.) A script starting with `#!/usr/bin/sudo -u bob -- /bin/bash` is executed by calling `/usr/bin/sudo` with the arguments `-u bob -- /bin/bash` and `/home/alice/script.sh`.

One solution is to use a wrapper script: make `/home/alice/script.sh` contain

```
#!/bin/sh
exec sudo -u bob /home/alice/script.real
```

and put the code in `/home/alice.script.real` starting with `#!/bin/bash` and make the sudo rule refer to `/home/alice.script.real`.

Another solution is to make the script reexecute itself. You need to be careful to detect the desirable condition properly, otherwise you risk creating an infinite loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
if ((EUID != 123)); then
  exec sudo -u \#123 /home/alice/script.sh
fi
```

(where 123 is the user ID of `bob`)

A simple solution is to tell people to run `sudo -u bob /home/alice/script.sh` instead of running the script directly. You can provide shell aliases, `.desktop` files, etc.

Comment: Telling people to run sudo directly is the *ideal* solution, unless they trust you or can read your shell script and be reasonably sure the program asking for their password is sudo.  This is less important if you have root, because in that case the person executing the script either trusts you or has already lost.

Comment: @Kevin I'm assuming that there's no password prompt here, as the question includes the `NOPASSWD` tag in its sudoers rule. Indeed if there was an authentication prompt then there would be a UI security concern, but that is not the case in the present scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try use alias:

```
alias bobscript="sudo -u bob ./script.sh"
```

and run:

```
bobscript
```

Comment: Your alias should specify the full path to `script.sh` - matching how it's defined in `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 0):

While not invoking sudo inside the script is probably best practice, a simple way to do it is using `env -S` to pass more arguments in the shebang line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S /usr/bin/sudo -- /bin/bash

# ...
```

Or, for a smaller line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S sudo bash

# ...
```